# make one ejb-jar uses another ejb-jar classess in the same EAR

Tags: java, deployment, ejb, ear

I've an EAR which contains two ejb jars..

I need for the second EJB Jar to access classes from the first EJB Jar...

Should I changed the deployment assembly for the second EJB jar, or It by default can access the classes of all jars within the same EAR ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trying it againest OC4J 10.0.3.n, I found that all Jars in the same EAR can see classes in each others....